# Cypress run some of tests in parallel

Tags: cypress

I have done lot of research of running some tests in parallel and some in series. Still, not have any great options for doing that. We'll have 4 virtual machines to done this. All tose vm's has own docker for application with own database as well. I have few tests which need to be run at the same machine.

I'll thinking can there be given some tags or something which can be configured so that spesified tags will run on VM 1 example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution by plugin named Cypress grep, link is below. With it you can write tags to tests like this:

```
it('works', { tags: '@smoke' }, () => ...)
```

run all tests tagged @smoke

```
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=@smoke
```

run all tests except tagged @smoke

```
$ npx cypress run --env grepTags=-@smoke
```

Install instructions and usage: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cypress/grep

Work the way as the Robot Framework tags.

Comment: But you're not really running anything in parallel are you.

Comment: @Aureuo Yes I'll driving in parallel, but needed tags to spesify which which tests are driven in parallel and which in series. Special case.

Comment: Well there's nothing here indicating the tests run in parallel, or that the tags are doing what you say.

Comment: @Aureuo I was figuring out how to group tests for making config which tests are driven parallel and which in series. Using tags for that.